# variable in react component is overwritten

Tags: reactjs, components

Hello I have the following situation:
in a method from a react component i have this code:

```
....

let saved = [...array];
    console.log(saved);

    setSaved(saved); //action
}

let days = [...array]; //same array
days[index] = value;

setDays(days); //action
```

in store both variables will set to the new value of days[index]
if I stop the code after setSaved with a return; the saved contains the array as it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))`